# How to get the current session user in Jenkins on a Groovy parameter

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I need get the current log in user in Jenkins, I am using a Groovy parameter but I don't know how to get that,

Thanks,

Comment: Isn't it `User.current()`?

Comment: Yes is it, thanks man I have several days searching  that

Comment: Added as an answer :-) Have fun!

Comment: returns SYSTEM !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to call:

```
import hudson.model.User
...
User.current()
```

From a groovy script to get the current user :-)

Comment: In script pipeline, it returns SYSTEM

Answer (score 3):

def user = build.causes[0].userId

Comment: Since `build` by itself doesn't exist it should be `currentBuild.rawBuild.causes[0].userId`, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction, User.current() does indeed return 'SYSTEM'. Have some points.

Answer (score 1):

```
import hudson.model.*

def job = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(env.JOB_BASE_NAME, Job.class)
def build = job.getBuildByNumber(env.BUILD_ID as int)
def userId = build.getCause(Cause.UserIdCause).getUserId()
def user = User.current()
println(user);
println(userId);


-----
this is the output 
[Pipeline] echo (hide)
SYSTEM
[Pipeline] echo
eefrat
[Pipeline] echo
eefrat
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a few words to help explain your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood... `userId` gives you the user who triggered the build or the user who's logged in?