# User.current() return null

Tags: gradle, groovy, jenkins-plugins, build.gradle

Jenkins version: 2.7.1
Issue: Even after using EnvInject Plugin, BUILD_USER doesn't appear as environment variable in build. I am using User.current().getId() in release plugin to retrieve user id. This plugin is built using gradle.

Is there a way that I can use to get currently logged in user.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please see if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24165316/how-to-get-the-current-session-user-in-jenkins-on-a-groovy-parameter

Comment: No..this won't work