# How to bring list of jenkins nodes to Active choice parameter and present only those for the current logged in user

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I have Jenkins job with active choice parameter with the name Computer.
Which groovy script I should write to bring me all the Nodes names, and present only the one for the current logged in user?
All nodes are with the label Desktop.
I tried the below but it doesn't work:

```
import hudson.slaves.DumbSlave

def users = []
for (DumbSlave it : Hudson.instance.getSlaves()) {
  if(it.getLabelString().contains("Desktop")) {
    def currAgent = it?.computer?.name
    if(currAgent != null) {
      users.add(currAgent)
     }
  }
}

return users
```

**Update (full answer with logged-on user, based on the below answer):**

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.model.User


def users = []
Jenkins.instance.nodes.each { node ->
  if(node.labelString.contains("Desktop")) {
    def currAgent = node?.computer
    def currAgentName = node?.computer?.name
    if(currAgentName != null) {
      def user = currAgent.systemProperties['user.name']?.toLowerCase()
      if (!users.contains(user) && user==User.current().toString()){
        users.add(currAgentName)
      }
    }
  }
}

return users
```

Comment: what do you mean by logged in user? logged in to Jenkins? the user who triggers the build?
note that you defined a List `def users = []` but used it as Map `users.containsKey..`
and IMO you should return a List at the end.

Comment: logged in to Jenkins. I agree I should return a list for active choice instead of map...

Comment: then I think that you are interested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24167308/947784 and not in `computer.systemProperties['user.name']`

Comment: Tnx! I added full answer in my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
import jenkins.model.*

def users = []
Jenkins.instance.nodes.each { node ->
    if(node.labelString.contains("Desktop")) {
        def currAgent = node?.computer?.name
        if(currAgent != null) {
            users.add(currAgent)
        }
    }
 }

 return users
```

Or make it Groovyer:

```
import jenkins.model.*

return Jenkins.instance.nodes.findAll { node ->
   node.labelString.contains("Desktop") &&
     node.computer.systemProperties["user.name"] == User.current().toString()
                                      }.collect { node ->
                                          node?.computer?.name }
```

Comment: Tnx! I added full answer in my question